# Hide header on scroll down,show it on scroll up(not working)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem,which showed yesterday,after i added a new div to my all page elements (wrapper) to make a slide and push effect on my mobile menu design.After i made the div and fixed all overflows and stuff,i noticed that my header function isn't working anymore..If anybody know where am i wrong please correct me,i will paste only header jQuery and Style.If you need any info for Wrapper div,just say what i will give you all info you need to help me.Thanks !

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
 "use strict";

 var MQL = 1170;

 //primary navigation slide-in effect
 if($(window).width() > MQL) {
  var headerHeight = $('.site-header').height();
  $(window).on('scroll',
  {
         previousTop: 0
     },
     function () {
      var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      //check if user is scrolling up
      if (currentTop < this.previousTop ) {
       //if scrolling up...
       if (currentTop > 0 && $('.site-header').hasClass('is-fixed')) {
        $('.site-header').addClass('is-visible');
       } else {
        $('.site-header').removeClass('is-visible is-fixed');
       }
      } else {
       //if scrolling down...
       $('.site-header').removeClass('is-visible');
       if( currentTop > headerHeight && !$('.site-header').hasClass('is-fixed')) $('.site-header').addClass('is-fixed');
      }
      this.previousTop = currentTop;
  });
 }
```

```css
.admin-bar .site-header {
  top: -80px;
}
.admin-bar .site-header.is-fixed {
  top: -160px;
}
.site-header {
position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 right:0;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .site-header {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .site-header.is-fixed {
    /* when the user scrolls down, we hide the header right above the viewport */
    position: fixed;
    top: -80px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
  }
  .site-header.is-visible {
    /* if the user changes the scrolling direction, we show the header */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  .site-header.menu-is-open {
    /* add a background color to the header when the navigation is open */
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
<span class="mobile-icon"></span>
   <div class="site-branding">
    <!--Logo and branding script,which i think it is uselless for my problem,so i won't show it to slow you -->
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1><?php endif; ?>    
  </div>
```

It is giving me error even here ;/

Comment: That error means that Jquery is not included prior to adding the script referenced

Comment: Well I am new to this,sorry for stupid mistake,i think i fixed it.It is 1 on 1 with my site and it was working yesterday,before i put that new div in my page..

Comment: Any suggestions:?

Comment: Do you get any other errors after fixing the Jquery issue?

Comment: I haven't touched jQuery in my site ,becaue it was working my mistake was here in the snippet.

Comment: What errors do you get in the console when using your code? Is it different than the error you get here?

Comment: Don't have any errors in console,just here ;/

Comment: I fixed it a little by adding .mobile-wrapper in my jQuery where it targets .mobile-wrapper .site-header,but it works only for like first 200 pixels of the page..